# ElasticSearch - query_string issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a query against multiple (7) fields and need wildcard support in all positions (end, start, middle). I was using query_string:

```
    { "query_string": { "query": "ABCD-EFGH",
      "fields": [ "f1^5", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6" ] }}
```

f1..f7 are strings using this analyzer:

```
  "analyzer": {
    "uppercaseAnalyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "filter":  [ "uppercase" ]
    }
```

So this works fine and wildcards work fine. However, some of the queries can possibly contain spaces, so:

```
    { "query_string": { "query": "AB CD  EFGH",
      "fields": [ "f1^5", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6" ] }}
```

fails. The user will enter as "ab cd  efgh" and I need to return "ab cd  efgh". I sort of got this working with "query": "\"ab cd  efgh\"", but that breaks wildcards.

Any solutions? I saw some older articles about escaping spaces with a backslash, but that generates an error in 2.3.

If I have to index 2nd copies of f1..f7 without spaces, that's going to double the size of my index.

If I use wildcard instead of query_string, it works as expected, but performance suffers.

Comment: the 2.3 documentation indicates that whitespace can be escaped, see the bottom section "Watch this space" on this page for example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html. Perhaps you're escaping the space incorrectly.

Comment: @Kevin - yeah, I saw that and as mentioned, it doesn't seem like it works. This works: { "query": "\"66  2409  14 K 4\"", ... quoting the whole string, but if I do "66\ \ 2409\ \ 14\ K\ 4", I get no hits. Get this error: "reason": "Unrecognized character escape ' ' (code 32)